# Tkinter Message widget does not take all the horizontal space

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create an help menu at the end of my app. I have used the `Message` widget for the same. My window is basically a grid with 2 columns. I have placed the message widget at the end and have spanned it across two columns, but however the widget does not take the entire horizontal space for some reason. Is there any way to force it to occupy all the horizontal space (while ensuring text wrap is present as it is present below)?

**Program Code:**

```
    self.helpDesc = """Help:
1. The URL textbox specified the URL to be watched. In order to verify whether the given URL is valid according to the program one could wait for the status code of the URL to appear in the next line.
2. Testing Again
    """

    self.helpBox = Message(self, text=self.helpDesc, anchor='w')
    self.helpBox.grid(row=10, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=N+S+W+E, padx=8, pady=8)
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

Comment: Try setting `padx` and `pady` to zero. They are external padding which is added to the outsides of the widget.

Comment: No, it doesn't make any major difference (just the padding on the left disappears)

Comment: ```anchor='c'```?

Comment: Try using a `Label` or `Text` widget instead. You'll have to wrap the text yourself with the former (but that's easy with the `textwrap` module).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a `width` parameter for your messagebox.  Those genereally use pixel values, whereas labels use how many characters are expected.  I believe there's a way to switch those, if need be, but I don't remember what that is.  Either way, this should get you closer to what you were aiming for.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import tkinter as tk

Title  = 'Text Wrap'
Width, Height = 600, 150
root  = tk .Tk() ; root .title( Title )
root .bind( '<Escape>',  lambda e: root .destroy() )
root .geometry( f'{Width}x{Height}' )

helpDesc = """Help:
1. The URL textbox specified the URL to be watched. In order to verify whether the given URL is valid according to the program one could wait for the status code of the URL to appear in the next line.
2. Testing Again
"""

lt = tk .Label( root, text='this', bg='white', width=int(Width/16) ) .grid( row=0, column=0 )
rt = tk .Label( root, text='that', bg='grey', width=int(Width/16) ) .grid( row=0, column=1 )

helpBox = tk .Message( root, text=helpDesc, width=Width, anchor='w' ) .grid( row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.W )

lb = tk .Label( root, text='the', bg='grey', width=int(Width/16) ) .grid( row=2, column=0 )
rb = tk .Label( root, text='other', bg='white', width=int(Width/16) ) .grid( row=2, column=1 )

root .mainloop()
```